# Easiest/fastest way to illustrate security experiment / reduction proof in cryptography

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have three examples of cases I need to draw (both security experiments and reduction proofs):
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm studying computer science and I wanted to create a "manual" for my exams. Problem: there are 30-50 security experiments + security proofs involved in the process. I need a fast and easy method to create those (hopefully in LaTeX). I hope you will help me.

They don't have to look 1:1 like what I have shown here; those three are just three examples of what I am looking for. I don't need fancy colouring and funny box colurs. I would prefer something like the very first image: simple and elegant.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{equation}
(PK, TD) \leftarrow Gen(1^n)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x \leftarrow^r x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y \leftarrow f_{PK}(x)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
if x = x' \; return \; 1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
else \; return \; 0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to use cryptocode. Or should I use tikz instead?

Comment: Do you know about the [`cryptocode`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cryptocode/cryptocode.pdf) package?

Comment: @egreg yeah, I've seen it, but I don't know how to use it. Tried it, didn't work, sadly.